# Facebook Log in Issue

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

I'm using Unity and prime31 plug in to access Facebook via my iPhone. I'm trying to test requests via my app by sending a request to a second test Facebook account on my iPhone (so I have my primary Facebook account and I've created a second one for the purposes of testing).

The problem I'm coming across is that I'm logging out of my normal Facebook account on the Facebook app and then logging into my test account. I'm then running my own app to test the requests. However, when I execute a 'me' graphrequest, it's still returning the details of my *primary* account (even though I logged into my test Facebook account before running my app).

I don't quite understand why it's doing this - I understand that there is a facebook settings page within iOS settings, but I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it?

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for this kind of questions. The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity.